# C++ Implementing an interface in two different classes

Tags: c++, interface

I'm trying to abstract a common interface for my gui implementation but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this cleanly. Here's a simplified version of what I'd like to achieve.

```
class IBorderable
{
    virtual unsigned int getBorderWidth(BorderIndex index) const = 0;
    virtual void setBorderWidth(BorderIndex index, unsigned int width) = 0;
};

class Square : public IBorderable
{
    // Implement while limiting BorderIndex to only 4
    // Calling with invalid BorderIndex is handled at compile time
};

class Cube : public IBorderable
{
    // Implement while limiting BorderIndex to only 6
};
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this through polymorphism without any conditional checks to make sure BorderIndex is within bounds. Is it possible to have it throw an error at compile time? I would have liked to use strongly typed enums but they can't be derived.

Comment: OT: Start by making those methods **virtual**. And what *type* is BorderIndex (odd it was left out of your source list)?

Comment: Your design is flawed. You cannot restrict a base contract in a derived class. What does IBorderable accept as a parameter?

Comment: @WhozCraig Wrote it a bit quickly and forgot in haste. Didn't think I'd need to put everything on here to get the general idea across. BorderIndex would just in this context be unsigned ints.

Comment: @n.m. Ah, what would be an alternative approach? And I'm not sure what you mean by what IBorderable accepts as a parameter.

Comment: I mean what is the permitted range of the `index` parameter. Is it infinite? Empty? Something else?

Comment: @n.m. 1 (e.g. a line) to infinity

Comment: The derived classes must also accept everything in that range.

Comment: @n.m. Accept but throw an exception?

Comment: If throwing an exception is in the specification of the interface, then derived classes can throw too, but then there's no static checking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid checking that at compile time is impossible without tricks that render the whole point of a common interface useless.
Doing it at runtime of course is easy.

The compiler that has only a IBorderable reference/pointer does not know what kind of derived object is behind that and it does not need to - thats the whole point of interfaces and virtual functions.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You should not need to know what the derived object is. Would it then be appropriate to just throw an exception at runtime within Square and Cube respectively?

Comment: Might be, yes. Inside the specializations of the functions having an BorderIndex parameter. Unfortunately its not the best performing solution doing checks like these on run time, but the only one retaining the structural aproach you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could make IBorderable a template, and use std::enable_if to make calls to invalid indices fail at compile time.

But I would suggest you make IBorderable a container containing n Border instances, and handle errors while accessing invalid indices at runtime. I feel the added complexity of a templated (compile-time max index checking) solution is not worth it.

Comment: Difficult?, I'd like to see how you restrict it using SFINAE for a *runtime* value parameter provided to either method. It would be an interesting piece of code to show.

Comment: The maximum is compile-time, as any Square class has a maximum of 4, while any Cube class has a maximum of 6.

Comment: I know what the question says, I was amplifying the difficulty in producing an SFINAE solution to *compile-time* range check a `run-time` parameter passed to a member, and as I said, you said in your first sentence it is possible, and I (and the rest of the world, no doubt) would be highly interested in how it is accomplished at, again, *compile-time*.

Comment: template <size_t MAX_INDICES> class IBorderable{ template<size_t I> Border* GetBorder(typename enable_if<I<MAX_INDICES>::type*); }; I said it was bad. It's not a runtime param? A square has 4 borders, a cube 6, this seems quite compile-time to me and therefore it should not be a problem to check.

Comment: I don't suppose you could move that to the answer and, while doing so, adjust appropriately so it compiles? Documenting the source parameters would certainly help as well. Ultimately, the runtime-first-param is the one i'm interested in seeing compile-time validated. I thought about it for awhile and never gelled to an extrapolated solution. SideNote: you're missing the default value on the type pointer, but I can live with that.

Comment: http://ideone.com/HHUnrk. I don't want to put it into the answer because it's a horrible travesty. Edited the answer to use stronger wording against such a solution.

Comment: Its really not that bad at all actually. Pretty clean for SFINAE, but its just not a *runtime* parameter, which was all I was stressing about the difficulty. I.e. there is no GetBorder(n) that is compile-time checkable for obvious reasons. For ensuring immediate const indexes are within range, your SFINAE is simple and elegant, though, nothing at all as ugly as you think.

Comment: Making the interface templated kills polymorphism - you need an additional layer of abstraction - the interface, the template checker, and then the derived class.